# Quartz Cron Job running every hour like 1PM, 2PM, 3PM, ... ,etc 24 times per day every day

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Im using Quartz Nuget Package to schedule a job to execute it every hour every day. For example it should be run @1.00PM, 2.00PM, 3.00PM, ... and so on 24 times per day.

Can you please advise how to script it in Cron Triggers in Quartz?

***UPDATE
The solution I applied the cron expression 0 0 23/1 ? * * * - every hour starting from 23.00 every day. Hope this will be helpfull to build similar cron expressions:
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

***UPDATE #2
I found a better way to script the required schedule: 0 0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 ? * * * - it is the cron expression to run Quartz jobs at 00:00,02:00,04:00 etc, every two hours.

Comment: What about daylight savings time, when the same time may occur more than once (and the two invocations may not be 1 hour apart)?

Comment: Hello, in our country we dont have daylight savings time, so it is supposed to be always the same regardless daylight savings time

Comment: Have you considered Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Did you try http://www.cronmaker.com/ ?

Comment: Hello, it is a great tool for cron expression constructing, thank you for the advise!

However, I need to set 24 runs of my job per day every hour. In fact my app should calculate and report water rate every hour. For example, calculation should be  done exactly @1.00PM, not 1.03 or 1.10PM. 

I'm thinking on writing 24 cron expression for each hour. But may be there is a better approach